# Lambda can only be used with functional interface?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, functional-interface

I did this:

```
public class LambdaConflict
{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        //*
        System.out.println(LambdaConflict.get(
            (str) -> "Hello World!! By ME?"
        ));
        /*/
        System.out.println(LambdaConflict.get(new Intf<String> (){
            @Override public String get1(String str){
                return "Hello World!! By get1 " + str;
            }
        }));
        /*****/
    }

    public static String get(Intf<String> i, boolean b){
        return i.get1("from 1");
    }
}

interface Intf<T>
{
    public T get1(T arg1);

    public T get2(T arg1);
}
```

and get this exception:

> incompatible types: Intf is not a functional interface
>           multiple non-overriding abstract methods found in interface Intf
>       Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get
>       full output
>       1 error

Is there any condition that I can't use lambda to replace anonymous class?

Comment: What do you mean by _overcome_ it? Do you understand the error?

Comment: 1) Functional interfaces must have only 1 method. 2) they must be annotated @FunctionalInterface

Comment: Fuctional interfaces are also called SAM types (Single Abstract Method Types). So, you can only have a single abstract method in your functional interface.

Comment: @RichardTingle: I think the the point 2 is not valid. They can be annotated but is not required.

Comment: @RichardTingle: The point about the annotation. Wouldn't that make already existing interfaces like `Runnable` non-functional?

Comment: @BheshGurung Intersting, you're right. "*Should be* annotated `@FunctionalInterface`" in that case

Comment: I guess this can be overcome by creating another (parent?) interface or by composition.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

No. There is no way to "overcome" this. A functional interface must have only one abstract method. Your interface has two:

```
interface Intf<T> {
    public T get1(T arg1);
    public T get2(T arg1);
}
```

Note: You don't need to annotate your interface as mentioned in comments. But you can use the `@FunctionalInterface` annotation to get compile time errors if your interface is not a valid functional interface. So it brings you a little bit more security in your code.

For more see e.g. http://java.dzone.com/articles/introduction-functional-1

Comment: Thanks for the tip about `@FunctionalInterface`!  I forget it has special properties.  Also, I found upgrading to the very latest JDK8 patch from Oracle also helps to improve error messages.  Older versions of JDK8 may sometimes allow code above to compile, but fail with an `java.lang.AbstractMethodError` at run-time.  Newer versions will reject at compile-time.

Answer (score 8):

Just for reference and to enrich the answers already given:

As per [JSR-335: Lambda Expressions for the Java Programming Language](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr335/index.html), in section Lambda Specification, Part A: Functional Interfaces it says:

> A functional interface is an interface that has just one abstract
>   method (aside from the methods of Object), and thus represents a
>   single function contract. (In some cases, this "single" method may
>   take the form of multiple abstract methods with override-equivalent
>   signatures inherited from superinterfaces; in this case, the inherited
>   methods logically represent a single method.)

So, what you need is to either provide a default implementation for one of your methods or put one of your methods in a different interface.

Answer (score 3):

Think about it:

- How should the compiler know if you want to override `get1` or `get2`?
- If you only override `get1`, what will be `get2`'s implementation? Even the code you commented out won't work because you don't implement `get2`...

There are reasons for this limitation...

Answer (score 1):

As stated by @Thomas-Uhrig, Functional Interfaces can only have **one method**.

A way to fix this, primarily because you never use `public T get2(T arg1);`, is to change the `Intf<T>` interface to:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface Intf<T>
{
    public T get1(T arg1);
}
```