# Unable to convert innerclasses into Lambda

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, inner-classes

I'm trying to learn Java Lamdas.

I'm trying to convert the following code into lambda representation but it's not working:

```
private void foo(Data data) {
    Observable.just(data).subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<Data>() {
        int count = 0;
        int pageCount = 0;

        @Override
        public void onNext(Data data) {
            Timber.e("onNext()");
            count = data.getCount();
            pageCount = data.getPage();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            Log.e("class", "onComplete");
            abc(count, pageCount);
        }
    });
}

private void bar(Data data) {
    Observable.just(data).subscribeWith({
        int count = 0;
        int pageCount = 0;

        data -> {
            Timber.e("onNext()");
            count = data.getCount();
            pageCount = data.getPage();
        },
        e  -> e.printStackTrace(),
        () -> {
            Log.e("class", "onComplete");
            abc(count, pageCount);
        }
    });
}
```

This is giving me error. I'm not really sure how to fix it.

Comment: Can you provide with the error you're getting?

Comment: subscribeWith() is a method of RxJava. I just clipped the other code because it's not really related to the current question

Comment: Please provide an example that actually complies.

Comment: Are you using RxJava ? , By the way your code started with a point i don't think it will execute.
Fix that first

Comment: I have updated the cdoe

Answer (score 4):

You missed one essential part. You can't just turn **any** anonymous inner class instantiation into a lambda.

Quoting from [here](http://www.journaldev.com/2763/java-8-functional-interfaces):

> The major benefit of java 8 functional interfaces is that we can use lambda expressions to instantiate them and avoid using bulky anonymous class implementation.

The core property of a functional interface: it has **one** single abstract method.

More details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23682243/lambda-can-only-be-used-with-functional-interface) for example.

Beyond that, I think the real answer is on a meta level: you have to understand what you are doing. Meaning: you don't use this or that concept because you heard about it, and someone said: "that is great". You use it because it makes sense in your context.

And of course, you can only decide whether something is useful, "the right thing" ... when you understand that concept. In other words: the real answer is to step back (for now); and study the concept of lambdas first. And to then decide where using it will give benefits to your code base.

Finally: as expressed by user Holger in the comments - there is another no-go in that inner class; as it contains fields; which are even "shared" by some of the methods; another aspect that **prevents** transforming this class into a single pure lambda.

Comment: How can I refactor the code above to achieve the lambda notation?

Comment: @user2498079 I don't think you can. If `subscribeWith` took three classes as arguments, each providing a single function, *then* you would be able to.

Comment: @user2498079 What makes you think you can? And see my updates to the answer.

Comment: Not only the number of methods to implement, also the fact that this inner class declares fields makes it ineligible for converting it to a lambda expression.